# Как в PL/SQL в качестве сообщения об ошибке в raise_application_error передать переменную типа varchar2?

Tags: oracle, plsql, переменные

У меня в функции есть проверка принятых параметров в PL/SQL на их равенство определённым значениям. Хочу накопить все ошибки которые собираются при проверке на многих условиях и после вывести одну ошибку, которая укажет на все нарушения при проверке условий. Вот отрывок кода, в котором показано, как я это делаю:

```
myErr varchar2 := '';

if ((myKvart > 5) AND (myKvart < 1)) then 
    myErr := myErr + 'Вы ввели несуществующий квартал. В качестве квартала введите число от 1 до 4 включительно.';
end if;

if ((lower(saled) <> 'да') AND (lower(saled) <> 'нет'))then 
    myErr := myErr + 'Вам нужно обозначить то, какие вас интересуют товары - проданые или нет. Если проданые - напишите да, если непроданные - напишите нет.';
end if;

if ((lower(poryadok) <> 'возрастание') AND (lower(poryadok) <> 'убывание')) then
    myErr := myErr + 'Вам нужно обозначить, в каком порядке вам нужно отобразить список товаров по их id. Если вас интересует расположение товаров по возрастанию - напишите возрастание, если по убыванию - напишите убывание.';
end if;

if ((lower(theYear) <> 'этот') AND (lower(theYear) <> 'пред')) then 
    myErr := myErr + 'Вы указали неправильный год. Напишите этот, если хотите обозначить в качестве года продаж этот год. Напишите пред, если хотите обозначить в качестве года продаж предыдущий год.';
end if;

if (myErr <> '') then
    raise_application_error(-20000, myErr);
end if;
```

Когда я ввожу в функцию значения, которые удовлетворяют условиям - функция корректно работает. А когда я ввожу в функцию значения, которые не удовлетворяют условиям, я получаю такую ошибку:

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
```

Хотя, как я посмотрел в документации Oracle - тип сообщения, которое принимает `raise_application_error` это как раз `VARCHAR2`.

Как вывести в качестве сообщения в `raise_application_error` переменную типа `VARCHAR2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут две ошибки:

1. Оператор `+` для строчных значений это действительно сложение, а не конкантинация строк, как во многих других ЯП. Эти значения будут неявно конвертированы в численные:

   ```
   select '1'||'2' + '3' res from dual;

          RES
   ----------
           15
   ```
2. Поиск ошибки идёт не там, где она возникла. Сокращение кода до минимального воспроизводимого примера помогло бы локализовать ошибку за считанные минуты:

   ```
   declare myErr varchar2 (32000) := '';
   begin   
       myErr := myErr + 'Вы ввели несуществующий квартал.';
   end;
   /
   ```

   > ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error